# Change the name of columns after they became rows values in unpivot query SQLSERVER2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have table with the following information:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApprovedPalmsInFarm](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FarmID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [kalas] [int] NULL,
    [khnizi] [int] NULL
```

The default result of select query is:

```
id  FarmID      kalas   khnizi
4   12100462    5        0
5   11520344    3        0
6   12104277    150      15
```

I wanted to generate report using Unpivot query where the columns become row values

My report query is as the following:

```
SELECT FarmID, PalmsName, Quantity
FROM [ApprovedPalmsInFarm]
unpivot
(
Quantity
  FOR PalmsName in ([kalas] , [khnizi] )
) u;
```

The result of my Unpivot query is the following:

```html
FarmID      PalmsName   Quantity
12100462    kalas        5
12100462    khnizi       0
11520344    kalas        3
11520344    khnizi       0
12104277    kalas        150
12104277    khnizi       15
```

Now my question is, how to change the name of the values of PalmsName while they are not understandable and they are the names of the columns so I would like to change the names for example to Arabic Language as the following:

خلاص instead of kalas

خنيزي instead of khnizi

Is it possible to change the name of the columns after they became row values?

Comment: You want to change the name of the values in your unpivot query? If so then this can be easily done by storing that query into a temp table then changing the values of the names in `PalmsName`. But I'm guessing you want to do it within the same query?

Comment: yes in the same query, is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, you can use a CASE statement (`CASE PalmsName WHEN 'kalas' THEN 'خلاص ' ... END AS 'PalmsName'` etc).  It'll be a bit clunky, but it'll work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made a comment, but I'll put an answer down here so it formats better:

```
SELECT 
    FarmID, 
    CASE PalmsName 
        WHEN 'kalas' THEN 'خلاص'
        WHEN 'khnizi' THEN 'خنيزي'
        ELSE PalmsName END AS 'PalmsName',
    Quantity
FROM [ApprovedPalmsInFarm]
unpivot
(
Quantity
  FOR PalmsName in ([kalas] , [khnizi] )
) u;
```

Comment: Didn't know that was possible with pivot/unpivot lol. +1 when I get my upvote counts replenished.

Comment: it gives me error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: I removed the else statment and I makde the query as the following

SELECT 
    FarmID,     
    CASE PalmsName 
        WHEN 'kalas' THEN N'خلاص'
        WHEN 'khnizi' THEN N'خنيزي'
        END
        Quantity 

FROM [ApprovedPalmsInFarm]
unpivot
(
Quantity
  FOR PalmsName in ([kalas] , [khnizi] )
) u;

it worked perfectly, I really appreciate your help

Comment: It's because @Jim forgot the to `END` his `CASE` :P.

Comment: Yep, missed the END.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also alias by creating a self contained subquery like so:

```
SELECT FarmID, PalmsName, Quantity
FROM 
(
SELECT FarmID, [kalas] AS [خلاص], [khnizi] AS [خنيزي] FROM
[ApprovedPalmsInFarm]
) AS apif
unpivot
(
Quantity FOR PalmsName in (apif.[خلاص] , apif.[خنيزي] )
) u;
```